# 4x4 Sliding Puzzle with a twist

Tags: visual, combinatorics, no-computers

For this puzzle, you're given a three piece set as depicted below:

- A blue indicator peg
- A square 4 x 4 tile frame filled with 16 tiles
- A max.8 tile holder / dispenser

[image: Puzzle Start Situation]

> **Your task is to un-scramble the tiles in the 4x4 frame to form a well-known pictogram.**

### There are of course a couple of rules:

- As a first step, you **choose a start position**. Place the blue peg on one of the light-blue rectangles of the 4x4 frame
- From now on, each of your moves consists of two parts:

  - First, **perform one action** in the row or column indicated by the blue peg
  - Then, **move the peg one step** further in a clockwise rotation
- The actions you can choose from on each move are depicted below.

  - **Rotate** one tile of the active row/column 90 degrees clockwise
  - **Remove** one tile of the active row/column and place it from the top in the dispenser stack. (Do not rotate the tile.)
  - **Place** the bottom most tile from the dispenser stack on an empty tile of the active row/column (Do not rotate the tile.)
- You *must not* skip an action in a move, i.e. you may never move the blue peg without performing exactly one valid action first.

> ### Find the *minimum number of steps* to unscramble the image.

---

### Visual instructions:

[image: Peg movement and active row/column]

---

[image: Rotating a tile]

---

[image: Adding a tile]

---

[image: Removing a tile]

---

### Notation

To describe your solution, use the following notation format:

- Specify the starting position as 1 - 16 
  <sup>(1 is the first on the top row, then clockwise)</sup>
- Each move:

  - Specify the tile as *distance from peg*, i.e. as @1, @2, @3, or @4 
    <sup>(@1 being adjacent to the peg and @4 furthest away from the peg.)</sup>
  - Specify the action as either:

    - rotate
    - add 
      <sup>(from bottom of dispenser)</sup>
    - remove 
      <sup>(to top of dispenser)</sup>

For example:

```
Start 5
@3: rotate
@1: remove
@2: rotate
@4: add
...
```

Comment: Is the [tag:no-computers] tag only intended to prevent brute-force, or am I also not allowed to make a program for myself just to play it, i.e. for better visualization of each move?

Comment: @LukasRotter Preventing brute-force (initially). I think it can be solved without, but if nobody does in a few days, I'll relax that condition. I just don't want it spoiled immediately.

Comment: BTW, I would recommend putting 16 "tile" images in PowerPoint or similar easy rotate/reassemble program.

Comment: Calling it a stack and having it behave like a queue is a little mean...

Comment: @BmyGuest would it be possible for you to add the 16 'tile' images somewhere so we can easily play with them? If it's too much trouble don't bother, but if it's easy it would be a big help.

Comment: Temporarily uploaded here. [PowerPoint](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54036297/PuzzleTiles.pptx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I left my original analysis below, but I think I have found an answer using 34 moves (30 is the bare minimum the puzzle could conceivably be solved in, but I do not know if that is possible or not)
Here is my solution as a gif, I can seperate out the images if you wish:

> [image]

And here is the solution as a move list, I numbered the rows and gave letters to the columns like this:
 [A1][B1][C1][D1]
 [A2][B2][C2][D2]
 [A3][B3][C3][D3]
 [A4][B4][C4][D4]

So starting with the dot at the top of column C, the moves are as follows:

> 1. Remove C4
> 2. Remove D1
> 3. Rotate B1
> 4. Remove A2
> 5. Remove B3
> 6. Remove B4
> 7. Remove D3
> 8. Remove C2
> 9. Place B4
> 10. Rotate A1
> 11. Place C4
> 12. Remove A3
> 13. Remove B2
> 14. Place D1
> 15. Place A2
> 16. Place B2
> 17. Place C2
> 18. Rotate D2
> 19. Rotate A1
> 20. Rotate A2
> 21. Place A3
> 22. Rotate D4
> 23. Rotate D4
> 24. Rotate C1
> 25. Place B3
> 26. Rotate A3
> 27. Remove A4
> 28. Place D3
> 29. Remove D2
> 30. Rotate A1
> 31. Place A4
> 32. Rotate B1
> 33. Rotate C1
> 34. Place D2

My strategy was:

> To pick up any piece that needed to be moved and then pick up either the piece that is in the spot it needs to go in or the piece which needs to go in it's now free spot. Otherwise just rotate any tile that needs to be rotated. At the end I needed to do some extra picking up of pieces, because to pick up and replace a piece is only 2 moves, but to rotate it fully is 4, so extra picking up cost less in the long run.

Original analysis below:

---

So I only just started trying to find an answer, but so far, I have discovered the obvious, which is that the tiles unscramble to

> [image]

and I did a little bit of analysis on the tiles to see how many moves it would take to get to the final image. R in this case stands for a single 90 degree Rotation clockwise, and M for another 'move' (I.E. if a tile needs to be both picked up and moved to a different location, that is 2 moves) So for each tile the Rotation and Move counts look like this:

> [image]
>  The numbers at the end of each row and column are just totals which I thought might be helpful. If you total all the rows or columns you get 30, so the solution has to take at least 30 moves.
>
> also, 9 tiles have to be physically moved, so the best way to go about solving this is probably finding the optimal way to pick up and replace those nine tiles, rotating the other tiles whenever picking up a tile or placing one isn't an option.

Comment: Very good systematic start to the problem. It's analysis like this why I didn't want a PC brute force right away.

Comment: The GIF is great, but could you also give the list of "commands" like in the question asked?  (*Easier to cross-check and follow up*). BTW, 34 is a good solution. My constructed one has 32. I don't know if a 30 move solution exists. I'll wait with the "accept" check for some other answers a bit (~a day) but essentially: Well done!

Comment: @BmyGuest I think if I started in a different place I might be able to get a 32 solution, or someone else might find it before then. I added a command list for the 34 step solution.